# NiFi: expression to test if attribute exists

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to optionally use an attribute if it exists, in an expression. I know I can use ifelse to determine this, however the attribute name is printed as a literal if it doesn't exist.

What is the correct expression to test for this?

```
${MyOptionalAttribute:notnull():ifElse(MyOptionalAttribute,'my default value')}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `UpdateAttribute` processor:

- `MyOptionalAttribute` (dynamic property): `${MyOptionalAttribute:notNull():ifElse(${MyOptionalAttribute}, "default value")}`